# Format specific words inside Word Table cell

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I'm new on C# development and I'm supposed to generate a Word Document programmatically.

At some point I'm doing this:

```
Paragraph p1 = document.Paragraphs.Add();
Table t1 = p1.Range.Tables.Add(p1.Range, 2, 1, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
t1.Range.Font.Size = 11;
t1.Style = style;
t1.Rows[1].Alignment = WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter;
t1.Cell(1, 1).Range.Select();
document.Application.Selection.TypeText(item.FullName + "");
t1.Cell(2, 1).Range.Select();
document.Application.Selection.TypeText(item.swca_description + "");
t1.Cell(2, 1).Range.Bold = 0;
```

My output in document looks like this:
[image]

First cell is what I intend to format (the `item.FullName`).

However it should look like this:
[image]

Any thoughts?

Edit:
This is how i create that string i need to give colors:

```
private string GetFullName()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(this.swc_datatype == null ? "void" : this.swc_datatype.swcdt_name);
        sb.Append($" {this.swca_name}(");

        foreach (swc_api_parameter inputParameter in this.swc_api_parameter)
            sb.Append($"{inputParameter.swc_datatype?.swcdt_name} {inputParameter.swcap_name},");

        if (swc_api_parameter.Any())
            sb.Length = sb.Length - 1;

        sb.Append(")");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

LE: I already have implemented a method like this:

```
        public static Paragraph AddRtfTextFromFile(this Document document, string rtfPath)
    {
        Paragraph p = document.Paragraphs.Add();
        p.Range.InsertFile(rtfPath, Missing.Value, false);
        p.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
        p.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri";
        p.Range.Font.Size = 12;
        p.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;
        p.Range.PageSetup.VerticalAlignment = WdVerticalAlignment.wdAlignVerticalTop;
        p.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

        return p;
    }
```

Comment: there's no reason to apologize for your English, its not bad at all!

Comment: Are you using Word Interop or any other library?

Comment: It's based on Interop, but i'm using the NetOffice Library. The reason i'm doing this is because the only requirement for the user is to have word installed, it doesn't mater which version.

Comment: The output in that cell looks like class definition with reserved words. "Void" has a color, class name another color, parameter type, and so on. These fields are introduced at some point in my app. It's a composed string. I can split it into separate words... but my issue is to give them specific color.

Comment: If you are okay with splitting the `item.FullName` into words, one approach would be to type a word, select the word, apply the color, collapse the selection, type the next word and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with splitting the `item.FullName` into words, one approach would be to type a word, select the word, apply the color, collapse the selection, type the next word and repeat. I don't know if there is any other method for this. But this might be a way for achieving what you need.

[image: Result of the below code]
Result of the below code

```
        Document document = new Document();
        Paragraph p1 = document.Paragraphs.Add();
        Table t1 = p1.Range.Tables.Add(p1.Range, 2, 1, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        t1.Range.Font.Size = 11;
        //t1.Style = style;
        t1.Rows[1].Alignment = WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter;
        t1.Cell(1, 1).Range.Select();

        document.Application.Selection.TypeText("void ");
        document.Application.Selection.MoveLeft(WdUnits.wdCharacter, "void ".Length, true);
        document.Application.Selection.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorSkyBlue;
        document.Application.Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

        document.Application.Selection.TypeText("item.FullName");
        document.Application.Selection.MoveLeft(WdUnits.wdCharacter, "item.FullName".Length, true);
        document.Application.Selection.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorRed;
        document.Application.Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);


        t1.Cell(2, 1).Range.Select();
        document.Application.Selection.TypeText("item.swca_description");            
        document.Application.Selection.MoveLeft(WdUnits.wdCharacter, "swca_description".Length, true);
        document.Application.Selection.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorBlack;
        document.Application.Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
        t1.Cell(2, 1).Range.Bold = 0;
        document.SaveAs(@"D:\Test.docx");
```

Also, please note that I have commented out `t1.Style = style;`. Uncomment as required.

Comment: Sounds like an good idea to start the approach. I'll try to implement in this way. I'll let you know if it works for me. The "item.FullName" will be split in words and I will output the formatted text into a ".rtf" file, and after that i will insert the file as paragraph in the cell. After that i will delete this temp file. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Why do you need to output the formatted text into a ".rtf" file, and after that insert the file as paragraph in the cell. After that delete the temp file?

Comment: Look at my LE. I can insert into a paragraph directly the content of an .rtf file, and it's more convenient for me to format a text from a file than to get each word from a cell. Correct me if i'm thinking wrong.

Comment: I have a very complex document as output with multiple dynamic created tables, images, different indentations, headings, Titles, Table of Contains and so on.

Comment: Okay. I understand.

Comment: `0` as the `Bold` property value did not work for me but `-1` did. So my solution is `table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Bold = -1;`. Hope this will help to someone.